# Travis CI GitHub integration not updating build status?

Tags: github, travis-ci

The Travis-CI build for [this GitHub pull request](https://github.com/iloire/WatchMen/pull/20) failed due to a problem installing a dependency. After updating it and trying again, [the build seemed to pass](https://travis-ci.org/iloire/WatchMen/jobs/51904899). However, the build status indicator displayed inline on GitHub is still reporting a failed build. Does anybody know why, or what can be done about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one build passed (35.3, the one on node 0.10.x), the [other two failed](https://travis-ci.org/iloire/WatchMen/builds/51907676), which means the build failed in total (even though one run was okay).

If the build on node 0.6 and node 0.8 are [*allowed* to fail](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-configuration/#Rows-That-are-Allowed-To-Fail), you can specify that in your `.travis.yml`. This would then lead to a successful build:

```
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - node_js: 0.6
    - node_js: 0.8
```

Or if you don't need those two extra builds, just remove 0.6 and 0.8 from your `.travis.yml`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I didn't realize I was looking at different Node versions. =)